# Strings Returned from Google MAPS API are Improperly Formatted

Tags: api, maps

Both the JSON and XML strings are improperly formatted and unusable upon a return from the Google Maps API.  This occurs using either Java script OR ASP script; 
I've tried both of them with no success.

Here is the code used:

```
Dim URL: URL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Anaheim,CA&destination=Corona,CA&sensor=false&prettyprint=true"

' Call the Google Maps API, using XMLHTTPRequest:
ReturnFromFunction = Get_Total_Driving_Distance_Google_API_XML(URL)
Response.Write(ReturnFromFunction)
Response.End

Function Get_Total_Driving_Distance_Google_API_XML(TheURL)

Dim XMLHttpRequest30
Dim XMLHttpRequest60
Dim sHTTPPostingStatus: sHTTPPostingStatus = null

XMLHttpRequest30 = "Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0"
XMLHttpRequest60 = "Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0"
XMLHttpRequest = "Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP"

Set oXML = Server.CreateObject(XMLHttpRequest)

    'SETUP TIMEOUTS-(NOTE: ONLY SUPPORTED IN XMLHTTPREQUEST VERSIONS 3.0 AND 6.0):
oXML.setTimeouts 100000, 60000, 60000, 360000

If TheURL <> "" Then

    oXML.open "GET", TheURL, false
    oXML.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/json"
    oXML.setRequestHeader "CharSet", "UTF-8"

    'Send the request:  
    oXML.send

sHTTPPostingStatus = oXML.Status
sReturnedString = oXML.ResponseText

End If  

'A status of 200 means HTTP posting is OK.  For other status codes, see referenced URL, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms767625(VS.85).aspx
If sHTTPPostingStatus = 200 Then

    Get_Total_Driving_Distance_Google_API_XML = sReturnedString
    Set oXML = nothing
    Exit Function

ElseIf sHTTPPostingStatus = 404 Then

    Get_Total_Driving_Distance_Google_API_XML = "XML document could not be found"
    Set oXML = nothing
    Exit Function
End If
End Function
```

You can see exactly what happens when this code is executed, by going to this URL:

http://www.edenusa.com/services/staging/stagequote_test.asp

You will see that the JSON returned is not properly formatted and non-parseable.
Worked on this for many hours already, with no solution as of yet.
Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Taking a closer look at this the JSON is in perfect format. If you go to an online JSON checker and paste the returned JSON, it is valid. That means the JSON can be parsed.

http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Plus, you need to check this out: in console, i get this error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Initialize_Java_Functions is not defined`

And check your page's encoding. It is not because of its format.

This article might be of use: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291499/Google-Maps-API-V3-for-ASP-NET

Comment: Thank you very much Hunter!  I got it all working quite well, using an ASP JSON parser that I found.  You are exactly correct!